# how to evaluate $\int\frac{e^x}{\left(\sin e^x+e^{-x}\cos e^x\right)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have tried substitution with integration by parts to make the function integrable but stuck at end point. Any method for last integral?

I have showed how i approach through this question by using integration by parts but stuck at last step. plz give me idea how to solve the last integral as my teacher solve this using same approach?

[image]

Comment: You need to type it in Latex otherwise no one will help!

Comment: But I am new here and do not know how to write it in latex???

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/displaystyle-int-fracx2xsinxcosx2-dx-is-equal-to/

Comment: [$\LaTeX$ tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach so far is correct. The remaining integral is $$\newcommand{\dif}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} \begin{align*}\int \frac{t\sec t\tan t + \sec t}{t\sin t + \cos t} \dif t &= \int \frac{\left(\frac{t \sin t}{\cos^2 t}+\frac{1}{\cos t}\right)}{t\sin t + \cos t} \dif t \\ &= \int \frac{t \sin t + \cos t}{\cos^2 t \left(t\sin t + \cos t\right)} \dif t \\ &= \int \sec^2 t \dif t \\ &= \tan t,\end{align*}$$ so the original integral, using your existing working, becomes $$\begin{align*}-\frac{t \sec t}{t \sin t + \cos t}+\tan t &= \frac{\sin t}{\cos t}-\frac{t}{\cos t\left(t \sin t+\cos t\right)} \\ &= \frac{t\sin^2 t+\sin t\cos t - t}{\cos t\left(t \sin t+\cos t\right)} \\ &= \frac{\sin t\cos t-t\cos^2 t}{\cos t\left(t \sin t+\cos t\right)} \quad \text{(using } \sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta \equiv 1\text{)} \\ &= \frac{\sin t - t\cos t}{t \sin t + \cos t}.\end{align*}$$